# How to Calculating Tenant Costs in SaaS based application in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, multi-tenant

How to calculating tenant costs in SaaS-based application with Autoscaled EC2 instance. How to calculate the compute charges for each user and how many users? Without using the containers.
Thanks in advance.